# How to print a value in loop after some delay in swift

Tags: swift, loops, dispatch-async

i want to print my values in loop after 5 seconds delay
here is how im trying to do so

```
let count = 1...10
for calls in count{
let seconds = 5
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(seconds), execute: {
print(calls)      
})
}
```

But it waits 5 seconds only in the first time and the print all the values at once.
Maybe there is another way to call a function many times after a delay of time please recommened

this is how im trying with timer

```
    var seconds = 10
var timer = Timer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let count = 1...10
    for number in count{
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            print(number)
    }
    
}
@objc func counter(){
    seconds -= 1
    if (seconds == 0){
        print("User Location")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why not use timer instead ?

Comment: @jawadAli same issue check out the code i have edit

Comment: See my answer. You're halfway there (you got rid of `Dispatch.queue` and are using a timer. But you really don't want to put the timer inside your loop - that's backwards. Instead, let the timer **be** the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Two pieces of criticisms. Forst, don't use a loop - it's executed immediately. Second, do use threading, there's no need. Use a `Timer` instead:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var timer = Timer()
    var iterations = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(printTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    @objc func printTime() {
        print(Date())
        iterations += 1
        if iterations == 5 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

}
```

It's output:

```
2020-08-15 18:08:38 +0000
2020-08-15 18:08:43 +0000
2020-08-15 18:08:48 +0000
2020-08-15 18:08:53 +0000
2020-08-15 18:08:58 +0000
```

After 5 iterations, you invalidate the time to shut it off.

Comment: what about sleep() ?would you recommend that?

Comment: I'm not sure, without more specifics. I'm not really seeing a reason to `print` something inside a loop, much less executing it timed. (Not in a finished app anyways.) What is it you *really* wish to do?